# virtual destructor signature

Tags: c++, virtual-destructor

For virtual mechanism we need to have method name same in base and derived classes.
However in case of virtual destructors, names can be different.

Can anybody explain how virtual mechanism(V-Ptr, V-Table) supports/works with differently named destructors.

Comment: the standard dictates the destructor's signature. what is there to explain?

Comment: I need to know how virtual mechanism works when virtual destructors have different names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's up to the implementation, just as long as it ensures that it can call the correct destructor. The means of doing so could be part of the general virtual mechanism, or it could be a special mechanism just for destructors.

One would expect that function names don't appear in vtables anyway: the compiler just assigns an offset into the table for each virtual function in each class. So the issue of whether destructors have names, and if so what they are, isn't relevant.

Comment: If names are not relevant, then why we keep same signature(method name,parameters) of base method and derived method for virtual mechanism.

Comment: @AjayShinde you're comparing apples and oranges. Destructors are just not like other methods, they're a particular breed.

Comment: @Ajay: there has to be a means for specifying that a function in a derived class overrides a virtual function in the base class. For normal member functions, it's the name and parameters that specify this. For destructors it isn't. Like Luchian says, destructors don't really override the base destructor anyway: marking a destructor `virtual` doesn't mean that a derived class can *replace* it, just means that deleting via a pointer or reference to base will work (call the derived destructor). Constructors and destructors are "special member functions" in the standad, they have special rules.

Comment: @SteveJessop: re your expection, the difference is that there is a special syntactic construct for calling a destructor, while there is no such special construct for calling a constructor. constructors therefore don't need to have names, while destructors do: §12.4/10 "In an explicit destructor call, the destructor name appears as a ˜ followed by a type-name or decltype-specifier that denotes the destructor’s class type".

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: aha, thanks. In some places the standard also refers to "pseudo-destructor-names" rather than "names".

Comment: @ Cheers and hth. - Alf: It is 12.4.13 (not 12.4/10) in Working draft. See http://cpp0x.centaur.ath.cx/class.dtor.html

Answer (score 1):

`virtual` destructors are treated differently than virtual functions. **All** destructors in the inheritance chain are called when an object is destroyed, as opposed to methods, where only the override in the most-derived class is called on invocation.

A `virtual` destructor is in essence identical to a non-virtual one, other than the fact that **it must be present** if you're going to delete an object through a pointer to a base class (otherwise it's undefined behavior).

Answer (score 0):

A class can have only one destructor, so there's no need for the name to be the same - you don't use the name to identify **which** destructor, because there is only one destructor per class.